# Redirect 301 /category/ /category/category/

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect the category to a sub category who have the same name of the category.

My code :

```
redirect 301 /abcd /abcd/abcd
```

But i've a redirect infinite.

```
/abcd/abcd/abcd/abcd/abcd/abcd/abcd/abcd/abcd/abcd.....
```

Same thing with that :

```
redirect 301 /abcd /abcd/efgh
```

I've got this :

```
/abcd/efgh/efgh/efgh/efgh/efgh/efgh/efgh/efgh/efgh.....
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `/abcd` is matching the rewritten URI also and causing this looping.

You should better use `RedirectMatch` that has regex support, so you do:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/abcd/?$ /abcd/efgh
```

Comment: Thanks but just a thing : i need to redirect "/abcd" and "/abcd/". Can you edit your reply? Thanks again

Comment: My regex `^/abcd/?$` is already making trailing slash optional so it will for both `"/abcd" and "/abcd/"`

Comment: Thanks. Bad tests. My fault. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
RewriteRule ^/abcd$ /abcd/abcd [R=301,L]
```